# Cache coherency issue with pgprot_cached mapping in ARM linux

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, cpu-cache

I am trying to use cached heap for camera preview using `pgprot_cached()` in `vm_pg_prot` for mapping a memory allocated by `ion_system_heap(alloc_pages)` to userspace. With this, I am getting a noise in camera preview. However, If I use `pgprot_writecombine()` or `pgprot_noncached()`, preview is proper. I tried `flush_cache_all()`, `dma_sync_sg_for_device()`, `dma_sync_sg_for_cpu()` for cache flush/invalidate before dumping the preview image to panel.
Is there anything else I need to take care?
Could this not be a cache coherency issue?

Comment: It is not clear which (if not both) devices use DMA.  Usually a display uses DMA, but probably the frame grabber does as well.  Is the code copying or doing plane/pixel manipulation?  The overall flow is not clear so I don't think anyone can say.  Just a power/noise issue with camera clock vs display might do something.  Is the CPU simultaneously drawing to the screen?  Where is the flicker; random or in specific spots.

Comment: Camera sensor uses DMA for frame grabbing. It then passes the buffer to Xserver which does the image post processing and dumps the image to the panel. Noise is present at specific spots in single launch of camera app. Noise spots are different in subsequent launches.

Comment: You can determine a lot by *spots*.  Is it a line (vertical/horizontal)?  If it is a cluster/area, then it doesn't seem to be cache.  'writecombine' is not useful with this device.  You need 'read conherency' type thing so that the CPU never uses cache; buffered reads are probably ok.  Do you use 'kmalloc()' or the [DMA infrastructure for allocation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt)?  It could be a virtual/physical issues.

Comment: The corruption is in the form of cluster/area. We are using alloc_page() for memory allocation. Can you please suggest how this can be resolved if we want to use pgprot_cached flag?

Comment: The allocated memory is mapped to IOMMU and is mapped to CPU with pgprot_cached. Camera sensor writes to IOMMU address. The preview image data read from CPU has corruption(hazy data).

Comment: This issue was resolved after disabling cache for buffer size less than L1 cache (i.e. 512KB), but I could not understand the actual reason. There was only one buffer less than this size in camera preview scenario.